# Adding dependencies to angular component created on the fly

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating and compiling an angular component at run time using JitCompiler, below is my code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Compiler, Injector, NgModuleRef, NgModule, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'web-application',
    templateUrl: 'creator.component.html'
})

export class CreatorComponent implements OnInit {

    result: any;
    @ViewChild('newCreatedComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) newCreatedComponent: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(
        private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {

        const template = `:) I am created dynamically`;
        const tmpCmp = Component({ template: template })(

            class MashupDynamicComponent implements OnInit {
                result: any[];
                constructor() { }

                ngOnInit() {

                }
            }

        );
        const tmpModule = NgModule(
            {
                declarations: [tmpCmp],
                imports: []
            })(class { });

        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
            .then((factories) => {

                const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
                const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);

                this.newCreatedComponent.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
            })

    }

}
```

I was wondering how do i pass dependencies to the component created on the fly? Like how can i use Http in the newly created component?

Comment: Have you tried to inject `Http` in constructor? If you have passed the correct injector it should work

Comment: @yurzui, yes i get an exception saying "cannot resolve all parameters for t", i tried injecting my own custom services etc but i keep getting the same error. Seems like the conventional way of injecting dependencies doesnt work in this method.

Comment: Try it with `@Inject` or add `@Injectable` to class

Comment: `constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) { }`

Comment: `constructor(@Inject(Http) t)`

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: When i try to use @Inject decorator in constructor, i get an error as below
"Decorators are not valid here"